# В ресурс вставить ссылку на другой ресурс

Tags: android, xml, строки

Вот к примеру имеем три текстовых ресурса:

```
<string name="tvTopText">Верхний текст</string> 
<string name="btnTopText">Верхняя кнопка</string> 
<string name="tvBottomText">Нижний текст</string>
```

Можно ли сделать что-то подобное с четвертым ресурсом?

```
<string name="btnText">Верхняя кнопка + " " + R.string.tvBottomText</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению таким образом сделать не выйдет, можете взглянуть в этом [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121802/android-reference-string-in-string-xml)